# File path in java code in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm new in java and Ubuntu. I want to know how can i write the right path of specific file in code as i got exception like that

```
/home/me/javaException in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
home/me/java/config.properites (No such file or directory)
```

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String queryFile = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        // load a properties file
        FileInputStream finputstream = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Do you have accessory permissions?

Comment: yes i have , but I've question why i got down vote ? i post screenshot of code and my error and ask specific question !!

Comment: *i post screenshot of code* that might explain the downvotes. We don't want screenshots, we want actual code. As in, text

Comment: why i'm on windows and my code in Ubuntu so fast for me to take screen shot and sent it to me to post here , I've problems in my lap !!

Comment: Is your properties file inside or outside of a JAR file?

Comment: don't see any piece of code about "ex.txt"

Comment: Side note: Consider to use the NIO.2 File API and the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: To get the path of the file type `readlink -f <filename>` in command line.

Comment: Thanks for everyone here helped and replied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ubuntu or any linux os your home folder is available in 'home/< username >'. You can check this from terminal or in gui. You can try some thing like,

```
File file = new File("/home/<your user name>/file.txt");
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("").getPath());
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath());
```

Maybe this is helpful.It prints the current class location and class path root

```
        System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

This prints the path where java command executes